# How to hide toast" Your audio will be sent to google to provide speech recognition service." in Speech Recognizer?

Tags: android, speech-recognition

[image]

I am using google speech recognizer for integrating voice services in Android but while pressing on mic buttong this annoying toast message is showing.please suggest me a way to hide this.

Thanks

Comment: did you solved it ?

Comment: just disable notification option from settings in Google app.

Comment: Have you seen this answer <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50692620/how-to-hide-toast-message-your-audio-will-be-sent-to-google-to-provide-speech-r/53512816#53512816>

Answer (score 1):

If your device is rooted you can hide the notification, but not prevent the audio from being sent to Google.

Install Xposed framework and module UnToaster Xposed, then add:
com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox

Answer (score 0):

So what you can do is to customize your speech recognizer by building it by your own. I wrote this code on xamarin.android so it should be pretty similar.

```
Public class CustomRecognizer : Java.Lang.Object, IRecognitionListener, 

TextToSpeech.IOnInitListener
{
private SpeechRecognizer _speech;
private Intent _speechIntent;


public string Words;


public CustomRecognizer(Context _context)
{
    this._context = _context;
    Words = "";
    _speech = SpeechRecognizer.CreateSpeechRecognizer(this._context);
    _speech.SetRecognitionListener(this);
    _speechIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ActionRecognizeSpeech);
    _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraLanguageModel, RecognizerIntent.LanguageModelFreeForm);
    _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ActionRecognizeSpeech, RecognizerIntent.ExtraPreferOffline);
    _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1000); 
    _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputPossiblyCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1000);
    _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputMinimumLengthMillis, 1500);
}

void startover()
{
    _speech.Destroy();
    _speech = SpeechRecognizer.CreateSpeechRecognizer(this._context);
    _speech.SetRecognitionListener(this);
    _speechIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ActionRecognizeSpeech);
    _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1000);
    _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputPossiblyCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1000);
    _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputMinimumLengthMillis, 1500);
StartListening();
}
public void StartListening()
{
    _speech.StartListening(_speechIntent);
}

public void StopListening()
{
    _speech.StopListening();
}

public void OnBeginningOfSpeech()
{

}

public void OnBufferReceived(byte[] buffer)
{
}

public void OnEndOfSpeech()
{
  startover();
}

public void OnError([GeneratedEnum] SpeechRecognizerError error)
{
    Words = error.ToString();
    startover();
}

  public void OnResults(Bundle results)
  {
    var matches = results.GetStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.ResultsRecognition);
    //do whatever you want for the result
  }
```

My code is a continuous recognition type,that's why I put **startover()** whenever the speech end. But you can customize this by making your own UI etc, just call **startover();** to begin the speech.

Comment: It should be working, because xamarin android use the native code (but on C#). Someone already asked similar question on stack overflow and implement this code on java.